# Ant-contrib : equals doesn't work in for loop

Tags: ant, stringtokenizer, ant-contrib

I have a file build.properties:

```
a=test1
b=
c=test2
```

And a file build.xml :

```
<property file="build.properties" />    

<for list="${a},${b},${c}" param="params">
    <sequential>
        <echo message="@{params}"></echo>
        <if>
            <equals arg1="@{params}" arg2=""/>
            <then><echo message="empty"/></then>
            <else><echo message="ok"/></else>
        </if>
    </sequential>
</for>
```

I obtain:

```
[echo] test1
[echo] ok
[echo] test 2
[echo] ok
```

But I want:

```
[echo] test1
[echo] ok
[echo] empty
[echo] test 2
[echo] ok
```

What's happen?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

The `for` task of Ant-Contrib uses the Java [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) class to tokenize the list of parameters. When tokenizing using this class, empty tokens are skipped, which is the case for property `b` in your case.

One solution is to add whitespace to the comma-separated list, and trim the token in the loop body:

```
<for list="${a}, ${b}, ${c}" param="params">
    <sequential>
        <propertyregex override="yes" property="trimmed.param" input="@{params}"
                regexp=" " replace="" global="true" defaultValue="@{params}" />
        <echo message="${trimmed.param}"/>
        <if>
            <equals arg1="${trimmed.param}" arg2=""/>   
            <then>
                <echo message="empty"/>
            </then>
            <else>
                <echo message="ok"/>
            </else>
        </if>
    </sequential>
</for>
```

Comment: Thank you ! And now, if i want replace <for list="${a}, ${b}, ${c}" param="params"> by <for list="a, b, c" param="params">, how can i do this ?

Comment: @user1517752 If you liked the answer from manouti, please mark it Answered.

Comment: @user1517752 I don't understand what you mean by the replacement? Could you update the question?